# "system running in low graphics mode" on 12.04, not fixed by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Tags: boot, graphics, fglrx

When I boot my Ubuntu 12.04, I get a screen showing:

> system running in low graphics mode

After referring to some forums and blogs, I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and did a reboot.

Still the problem was not resolved.

Then I installed the driver

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Still faced the problem.

I have all important data and have installed much software.
It would be helpful if someone could suggest how to resolve the issue

Comment: Yes, I did go through the link you have mentioned. My system has intel hd graphics card. so, should I try running the following commands : sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates -y. I am not able to understand what went wrong. Can u reason it?

Comment: Post what you have tried and the outcome in your question.